# Bash colorization needs on code and its ouput lines

Tags: bash, pipe

How exactly is the Bash way to fulfill/solve needs of combination of

When writing error messages as occurs in between code lines written by xtrace upon the executed script/codes, with set -x, the error message must get colorized to a different color contrast to the output xtrace lines, while both the error and xtrace lines itself already has been stderr.

Any workaround effort to solution please

Comment: This sounds like homework. But see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8414/how-to-have-tail-f-show-colored-output